# Error when trying to install HAXM

Tags: android

I tried installing haxm but get an error message saying that "HAXM" cannot be installed until VT-x is enabled." I went into my bios and enabled VT-x but i am still getting the same error. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling Hyper-V if you are running windows 8.1, restart your computer and try installing HAXM again.